# Linear Independence Matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, linear-programming

Suppose we have a m by n matrix A with rank m and a set K⊆{1..n} such that the columns of A indexed by K are linearly independent. Now we want to extend K and find a set L so that k⊆L and columns indexed by L are linearly independent too.

One way of doing it would be to start adding column indexes to K and test if the new set are linearly independent or not by using Gaussian Elimination for example. But is there a better way so that I would not need to test for every index added.

Thank You

Comment: Anybody else think this smells like homework?

Comment: I've already stated the answer above, just wanted to know since we have set to start with, is there a better method of achieving this.

Comment: you could iterate over all sets of column vectors of order m and check linear independence via computing the determinant of the resulting m by m matrix; the preconditions guarantee that this'll work

Comment: You need to do only one Gaussian Elimination. You transpose the matrix, do the first |K| steps on vectors from K and do the rest on the others in any order. You then add every non-zero vector to the set L. This is O(n * m^2). So if I understand correctly, this is slow and you need faster?

Answer (score 1):

Only because no one officially answered yet... can't you just use QR?

```
Q, R = qr(A)
```

QR factorization finds orthonormal matrix Q and upper triangular matrix R such that A = QR. It implements the Gram-Schmidt algorithm for finding an orthonormal basis for A.

The columns of Q are orthonormal, hence linearly independent. And the first n columns of Q span the column space of A. So Q should give you what you want.